# ROS Melodic 1.6 Environment setup No such file error

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After loading Melodic successfully before, downloading ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.2amd64 has presented me with a small but strange error. I followed all the install instructions.
At the very end during 1.6 Environment setup:
source ~/.bashrc
I am presented with:
bash: /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file or directory.
It looks like the opt directory is empty, no ros directory.
As I open a new terminal I get
bash: /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file of directory.
I think I've always seen a ros directory in opt.
The solution seems like it could be simple. First time experiencing issues loading Melodic.
Considering another wipe/reload using later components.
Thanks for any solution in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323694/ros-melodic-1.6-environment-setup-no-such-file-error/) by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I wiped and reloaded ubuntu and Melodic again. What I did differently this last time, was to take extra 20 minutes during ubuntu installation to log into ubuntu one in order to download ubuntu updates prior to downloading Ros Melodic. Lesson learned. No errors, no problems. Followed Ros directions.

---

Originally posted by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) with karma: 26 on 2019-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
Did you not see errors while running `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop` or similar commands?

"Ubuntu One" should not be needed here. A regular `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install <pkg>` should suffice.

**Comment by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on 2019-05-22**:
Correct. Except it takes me too long to download a fresh .iso from ubuntu.com every time one of my poorly recreated Gazebo Frankensteins blows one or more of my test box' OS away. To save time, I use an 18.04.2 amd64 downloaded a couple of months ago. It is probably true if you don't simulate new features every month, or do a fresh ubuntu download, then you do not need to update ubuntu in order to download ros Melodic. I save around a day's worth of waiting by reusing a 2-month-old shelf copy of ubuntu .iso. I, unlike others who load a fresh .iso, have to update ubuntu in order to avoid broken ROS installs. Thank you for your comment and I hope my short comment helps the whole world to continue building robots with ros.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-23**:
I'm not saying you shouldn't update your Ubuntu installation.

The first thing you'd do *after* installing Ubuntu would be `sudo apt update` and then a `sudo apt upgrade`.

After that you can continue installing ROS.

Depending on your internet connection this should not take a day, but if it's very slow that could of course happen.

My confusion was with the remark about "Ubuntu One".

> Except it takes me too long to download a fresh .iso from ubuntu.com every time one of my poorly recreated Gazebo Frankensteins blows one or more of my test box' OS away.

I still don't understand how user-level code in your home directory is able to "blow away" an OS install, but if you prefer to reinstall everything that is of course fine.